# How would you compare two arrays and filter between the two arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

So my first state sortedFavorites:

[image]

This is my second state watchedFilter:

[image]

So sortedFavorites state contains everything watchedFilter state contains, what I want to do is that compare the two arrays and filter out everything which both sortedFavorites and watchedFilter have in common. So I don't want any of the movies in watchedFilter to be in sortedFavorites.

For example: sortedFavorites= {1,2,3,4,5} watchedFilter={1,2,3}
The result I desire is: sortedFavorites={4,5}

This is what I tried but it doesn't do anything:

```
filterFavorites = () => {
    let showFavorites = this.state.sortedFavorites.filter(fav => !this.state.watchedFilter.includes(fav))
    this.setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        ...{ sortedFavorites: showFavorites }
    }));
}
```

Comment: isn`t desired result be sortedFavorites = {4,5}

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Do the two arrays contain the same objects, or are they separate objects with just the same data?

Comment: So, sortedFavorites contain all the objects in watchedFilter plus more and watchedFilter only contains parts of sortedFavorites

Comment: Yes, I understand. But are they the same objects, i.e. do they have the same object references? Is `sortedFavorites[3] === watchedFilter[0]` in your example?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: What I am saying is that any objects in watchedFilter should be removed from sortedFavorites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new array with all entries from `sortedFavorites` that are not in `watchedFilter`.

Since there are separate objects in both arrays `includes` will not work, because that will check for *exact object references*. You can check if the `id` is the same instead:

```
filterFavorites = () => {
  this.setState(previousState => {
    const sortedFavorites = previousState.sortedFavorites.filter(
      fav => !previousState.watchedFilter.some(w => w.id === fav.id)
    );

    return { sortedFavorites };
  });
}
```

Comment: The funciton above adds the objects of watchedFilter into sortedFavorites.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't do anything. The watchedFilter object in sortedFavorites stays the same.

Comment: @rockwire Are you sure that `sortedFavorites` will contain more entries than `watchedFilter`, and that there are the same object references in both? Something doesn't add up.

Comment: It doesn't matter if sortedFavorites has less movie objects than watchedFilter. What I need is that any same object from sortedFavorites and watchedFilter should be removed from sortedFavorites. For example : sortedFavorites={mission impossible, ocean 11} and watchedFilter={ocean 11, thor ragnarok, rampage}. So the function should make sortedFavorites={mission impossible}.

Comment: Yes, and if that is true, and `sortedFavorites[1] === watchedFilter[0]` in your example, because they are *exactly the same object reference*, then the above code will work. You can try `const sortedFavorites = previousState.sortedFavorites.filter(fav => !previousState.watchedFilter.some(w => w.id === fav.id));` and see if you get a different result. i.e. it's not the same object references in the arrays.

Comment: @rockwire You're welcome! Great, I updated the answer.